# The Windows Media Player doesn't play *.mov files :( Plese give me any suggestions

Tags: javascript, wmp

```
 <html> 
<head> 
  <title>so-wmp</title> 
  <script> 

    onload=function() { 
      player = document.getElementById("wmp"); 
      player.URL = "test.mp3"; 
    }; 

    function add(text) { 
      document.body 
        .appendChild(document.createElement("div")) 
        .appendChild(document.createTextNode(text)); 
    }; 

    function handler(type) { 
      var a = arguments; 
      add(type +" = "+ PlayStates[a[1]]); 
    }; 

    // http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb249361(VS.85).aspx 
    var PlayStates = { 
       0: "Undefined", // Windows Media Player is in an undefined state. 
       1: "Stopped", // Playback of the current media item is stopped. 
       2: "Paused", // Playback of the current media item is paused. When a media item is paused, resuming playback begins from the same location. 
       3: "Playing", // The current media item is playing. 
       4: "ScanForward", // The current media item is fast forwarding. 
       5: "ScanReverse", // The current media item is fast rewinding. 
       6: "Buffering", // The current media item is getting additional data from the server. 
       7: "Waiting", // Connection is established, but the server is not sending data. Waiting for session to begin. 
       8: "MediaEnded", // Media item has completed playback. 
       9: "Transitioning", // Preparing new media item. 
      10: "Ready", // Ready to begin playing. 
      11: "Reconnecting" // Reconnecting to stream. 
    }; 

  </script> 
  <script for="wmp" event="PlayStateChange(newState)"> 
    // http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb249362(VS.85).aspx 
    handler.call(this, "playstatechange", newState); 
  </script> 
</head> 
<body> 
  <div id="page"> 
    <object id="wmp" 
       classid="clsid:6BF52A52-394A-11d3-B153-00C04F79FAA6" 
          type="application/x-oleobject"> 
    </object> 
  </div> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: dont use movs or windows media player. theres two very good suggestions for you ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`.mov` files are QuickTime files](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.mov). Windows Media Player does not play QuickTime files out of the box.

QuickTime is an application created by Apple. Windows Media Player is an application created by Microsoft. Surprised that they're not immediately compatible? You shouldn't be.

**The solution:** as [@Andrew Bullock](https://stackoverflow.com/users/28543/andrew-bullock) commented, don't try and use them together (in a browser, at least). Use a different player, or a different multimedia format.

Comment: This is a commentary, not an answer.  The question still remains if there is a way play a MOV in Windows Media Player ... i.e., installing a custom codec.

Comment: If you think it's a comment and not an answer, flag it as such.